# Man in the middle legitimate packet inspection

Tags: wireshark, packet-analysis

we're trying to debug a faulty Panasonic Mobile softphone SIP app (both Android & Apple versions), as  many calls are randomly dropped unexpectedly.
This is the conceptual connection diagram:
[image]

We want to ensure that our setup is not conflicting somehow, who knows if the router, the switches or access points are dropping packets to such an extent which will make communication fail?

Data:

```
Core LAN 192.168.8.0
VLAN Staff 10.0.100.0
VLAN Guest 10.0.200.0
VLAN PBX 172.16.4.0
```

- Mobile phones running the app may connect to WIFI on Core LAN or VLANs Staff, Guest
- PBX and hard phones are running on VLAN PBX
- Apps require Internet access to authenticate to Panasonic servers, then communication with PBX is established

How could we capture all traffic from a handset running the app to the PBX? Is there a sort of legit man-in-the-middle technique that can be use (sort of Wireshark)??

Comment: Wireshark is exactly what I would use.  Your PBX should provide some sort of logging information.  Do phones stay associated/registered with the PBX?

Comment: There's a sort of syslogging on the PBX, but lacks of useful information. There's a log on the phones that will show useful data. What I miss is where would I run Wireshark, assuming none of the devices in the game will allow running (router, switches, PBX & mobile app)

Comment: If you can't configure port mirroring (monitoring) on any of the devices, you will need to install another device (switch) where you can.

Comment: Could stretch this a bit? Rookie here!

Comment: monitor span on the port(s) going to the PBX. (or a physical network tap, but those things are expensive)

Comment: I have read that ARP spoofing combined with Wireshark can help...

Comment: Can you configure your network switches?  What model are they?

Comment: We use Ubiquiti Unifi switches & APs, then all traffic is routed through a Peplink Balance One router, which does intervlan routing and WAN access

Comment: This link on the Ubiquti site [regarding port mirroring](https://community.ui.com/questions/How-to-Enable-Port-Mirroring/618cbb8d-c07b-49a2-aaaf-4bb01bfea702) may help you.

Comment: Can you add to your question a brief network diagram describing the connectivity between the PBX and some of the problematic VOIP phones or softphones?  That will help understand your options for traffic inspection.

Comment: The diagram you provided is the vendor ideal diagram, not a diagram of your specific implementation. There is no Ubiquiti or any other devices you actually have in your network. What was being asked was that you provide a diagram of your implementation so that we can see where you may be able to mirror traffic.

Comment: Got it to work with port mirroring! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Ron will accept as solution, if proposed!